# OpenVPN to access my company's VPN

Tags: mac, vpn, openvpn

I want to access the VPN setup at my office place from my macbook. I tried accessing the [VPN by creating a VPN interface in Network Preferences](https://superuser.com/q/270661/44422) BU all in vain. I am now trying to connect to the VPN using VPN clients for Mac. I came across [OpenVPN](http://openvpn.net) but I want to know if it can be used to access a private network like the one setup by my company or is it something like I have to create a server on OpenVPN and then access it on a client at home.

Comment: What VPN technology does your company use?

Comment: As Matt said, you will need to speak to the technical staff at your office to determine what VPN technology they are using.

OpenVPN is a specific VPN type (VPN over SSL). The most likely situation is that your office VPN is either PPTP (Microsoft) or a Cisco VPN. In either case, you will need an IP address to point your client at, and authentication credentials... either a login/password, or sometimes, a certificate file.

Comment: It's using L2TP over IPSec.

Comment: I got the server IP address, a username, password and an authentication keyword from my company. Will that suffice?

Comment: What @gerryk is trying to say is that you need to be using the same type of VPN software on both ends of the VPN.  If your company isn't running OpenVPN on their end, you can't connect to it using OpenVPN.  No matter what information you have.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using snow leopard I believe it is:

System Preferences>Network

Click on the + sign, select VPN and add your details.

The above is from memory as I don't have access to my mac atm.

Comment: Hello there. As I said I have tried this in vain - http://superuser.com/q/270661/44422