# Access L2TP over IPSec VPN using OpenVPN on Mac?

Tags: mac, vpn, openvpn, l2tp

Is this possible? To connect to L2TP VPN using OpenVPN on Mac?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OpenVPN only supports the "OpenVPN" protocol. You cannot use it to connect to L2TP/IPsec networks.

Answer (score 0):

Check out the answer to your [earlier post](https://superuser.com/questions/271199/openvpn-to-access-my-companys-vpn)